# JBoss 7.1 how to deploy ear/war to an external directory

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x

in JBoss 7.1, the default deploy directory is standalone/deployment.

I want to change this default to an external directory. I know in JBoss 5, I can specify this in profile-repository.xml.

How to do this in JBoss 7.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [deployment scanner](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Scanner+configuration) configuration. You can change the path to whatever or you want. Another option would be to use the default one, but add an additional deployment scanner for your other directory.

Comment: thanks, that works. also found the following link [Deploying an application from an external deployment location](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DeployingAnApplicationFromAnExternalDeploymentLocation)

Comment: Another point to remember is that the "Default" deployment in AS7 isn't necessarily via the Deployment Scanner. You can also use the Management Console or Management CLI to deploy your application to the content repository, and not be reliant on your filesystem to manage the source file.