# Jboss setup similar to Weblogic domain?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

We use Weblogic 12 in our application and create a custom Weblogic domain in system and deploy application to it.

I know that in Jboss 7.1.1 we can copy application to ./standalone/deployments to deploy the application.

But is it possible to create a domain similar to Weblogic in Jboss, so that application can be started from some other location even though it isn't copied inside ./standalone/deployments?

Comment: I guess this link answers my question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505856/jboss-7-1-how-to-deploy-ear-war-to-an-external-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called domain mode.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Domain+Setup

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Please look at my answer below

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can achieve this by configuring deployment scanner. But also with domain mode you can upload application to domain controller and deploy it automatically to the all other servers. Domain mode actually provides much more functionality, like distributing configuration, JVM parameters or deployments among servers etc.